# sql connection timeout

Tags: sql-server, fluent-nhibernate

i have my server written with structure map and fluent nhibernate,
when i run my server from my pc and direct him to the db on another server i get a sqlexception that tells me that the timeout expired

this is the message :
Timeout expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding.

the line in code that marked on debug  is

_transaction = _session.BeginTransaction();

any suggetions?
the db is mssql 2008

Answer (score 0):

First thing to do is make sure you have connectivity to that other database.  Open management studio and try to connect.

If that connects, then you need to make sure you have all of your settings setup correctly.  Check the web.config and the hibernate.xml file.